# React NativeTypError: undefined is not an object

Tags: api, react-native, promise

I am getting this error while making an API call:
`Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id:0): TypError: undefined is not an object(evaluating 'json.main.temp')`.

this is my state:

```
this.state = {
      weather:{
        city: null,
        temperature: null,
        wind:{
          direction: null,
          speed: null
        }
      },
      latitude: null,
      longitude:null,
      error: null
    }
```

My componentWillMount function:

```
async componentWillMount(){
    await this.getLocation();
    await this.getWeather();
  }
```

My getLocation function:

```
async getLocation() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        this.setState({
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude,
          error: null,
        });
      },
      (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
      { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 },
    );
  }
```

getWeather function:

```
async getWeather() {
    try{
      let url = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' + this.state.latitude + '&lon=' + this.state.longitude + '&appid=<my app id>&units=metric'
      console.log(url);
      fetch(url).then(res=>res.json())
      .then(json=>{
        console.log(url);
        this.setState({
          weather: {
            city: json.name,
            temperature: json.main.temp,
            wind: {
              direction: json.wind.direction,
              speed: json.wind.speed          
            }
          }
        });
      });
    }
    catch(error){
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
```

The json you get from the API:

```
{  
   "coord":{  
      "lon":6.14,
      "lat":52.79
   },
   "weather":[  
      {  
         "id":804,
         "main":"Clouds",
         "description":"overcast clouds",
         "icon":"04d"
      }
   ],
   "base":"stations",
   "main":{  
      "temp":11.49,
      "pressure":996,
      "humidity":81,
      "temp_min":11,
      "temp_max":12
   },
   "visibility":10000,
   "wind":{  
      "speed":8.2,
      "deg":240
   },
   "clouds":{  
      "all":90
   },
   "dt":1543829100,
   "sys":{  
      "type":1,
      "id":1530,
      "message":0.1147,
      "country":"NL",
      "sunrise":1543822083,
      "sunset":1543850543
   },
   "id":2746766,
   "name":"Steenwijk",
   "cod":200
}
```

The console log in the getWeather function logs the latitude and longtitude as "NULL". I think it is because the getLocation function isn't done yet. I have no clue what to do to make it work.

Comment: The json you have shown above did the same response is logged when you console it in getWeather function because as you said that lat lng are being passed as null so i think you are not getting the above response you are expecting because lat lng are going as null in api request.

Comment: Apperently the getweather function makes the call before getlocation passes the values to it. I fixed this by checking if it was NULL. And calling the function again.